# Show "hexagonal elliptic curves" have algebraic coefficients

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, riemann-surfaces, conformal-geometry, elliptic-functions

**Introduction**:
Given any $\tau \in \mathbb H$, there is an elliptic curve $y^2=4x^3-g_2(\tau)x-g_3(\tau)$ which has $\{1,\tau\}$ as its lattice. Wikipedia gives an "explicit" relation between $g$ and $\tau$

\begin{align*}
 {\displaystyle g_{2}(\tau )=60\sum _{(m,n)\neq (0,0)}\left(m+n\tau \right)^{-4}} &\quad & & {\displaystyle g_{3}(\tau )=140\sum _{(m,n)\neq (0,0)}\left(m+n\tau \right)^{-6}}
\end{align*}

---

**Question**:
Let $\tau=a+b\omega$ where $a,b\in \mathbb Q$ and $\omega=(-1+i\sqrt{3})/2$. Can we show $g_2(\tau), g_3(\tau)$ are algebraic?

---

**Motivation**: The triangular lattice of $\mathbb C$ is invariant under translations by $n+m\omega$, where $n,m\in\mathbb Z$. Hence, given an elliptic curve whose periods are $\{1,a+b\omega\}$, we can quotient and get an equilateral triangulation of the elliptic curve (torus).

This is related to Belyi's theorem which says a compact Riemann surface can be equilaterally triangulated iff the Riemann surface can be defined as a zero set of polynomials with algebraic coefficients.

Since the above elliptic curves admit an equilateral triangulation, Belyi says it can be described by polynomials with algebraic coefficients. One can ask: is $g_2(\tau),g_3(\tau)$ algebraic and is there an easy way to see this?

---

Comment: The keyword you should search for is “complex multiplication”.

Comment: @Aphelli, could you expand a little more?

Comment: Let $\tau \in \mathbb{H}$ be algebraic of degree two over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then the elliptic curve $E=\mathbb{C}/\tau\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ has a special structure: its endomorphism ring is bigger than $\mathbb{Z}$, and one says that it has *complex multiplication*. This implies (it’s not trivial but it’s classical) that $E$ is defined over some number field. In particular, the $j$-invariant of $E$ (which is $j(\tau)$, perhaps up to normalization) is an algebraic number. The keyword you need to search to get more information about this is “complex multiplication”.

Comment: Thinking a bit more, I’m not sure that’s the correct point of view, though… For instance, it’s fairly easy to see that $g_2(\omega)=0$, but I don’t know if anything is known about $g_3(\omega)$ (though “complex multiplication” would still be one of my keywords, along with “modular forms” or maybe “Eisenstein series”, since that’s what $g_2$ and $g_3$ are)… it can be written as a (somewhat) natural infinite product over primes of $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$, which makes me suspect that deciding its algebraicity is a very difficult problem, barring some coincidence (eg $\pi$ pops up)…

Comment: Could you tell more about why $g_2(\omega)=0$?

Comment: $g_2(\omega)$ is the sum of the $x^{-4}$ over the nonzero $x \in \mathbb{Z}[\omega]$. Consider the variable change $y=\omega x$.